# UPDATE EACH result from SELECT STATEMENT (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, foreach, sql-update

I'm trying to write a query which updates each resulting row from a SELECT statement.

```
SELECT u.P_ERPNUMBER, a.P_ERPNUMBER
from users u
inner join orders o on o.USERPK = u.PK
inner join addresses a on a.pk = o.PAYMENTADDRESSPK
where o.STATUSPK = 8796095414363 AND a.P_ERPNUMBER is NULL AND o.CODE in ('PL3001442611','PL3051023794');
```

The above query returns the values **[ u.P_ERPNUMBER ]** I need to use to UPDATE each field **[ a.P_ERPNUMBER ]**.

I have tried to nest the SELECT query inside an UPDATE statement shown below but it returns a 'multiple row' error... it would work one by one but I need it to be a batch process.

```
UPDATE ADDRESSES
SET P_ERPNUMBER = (
    SELECT u.P_ERPNUMBER
    from users u
    join orders o on o.USERPK = u.PK
    join addresses a on a.pk = o.PAYMENTADDRESSPK
    where a.P_ERPNUMBER is NULL )
where PK in ( SELECT PAYMENTADDRESSPK FROM ORDERS
WHERE STATUSPK = 8796095414363 AND CODE in ('PL3001442611','PL3051023794'));
```

What's the correct way of updating each `a.P_ERPNUMBER` with  its joined `u.P_ERPNUMBER` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove join addrress from sub query and use the address table you are updating:

```
UPDATE ADDRESSES a
...
join orders o on o.USERPK = u.PK
WHERE a.pk = o.PAYMENTADDRESSPK
AND a.P_ERPNUMBER is NULL )
```

Comment: You rock! Thank you so much :)